# What is a word to describe something that easily spirals into the next?

Tags: synonyms, vocabulary

I'm looking for a proper word to describe what happens when one thing predictably leads into the next thing. I'm using it in the context of describing a video game I play. When a certain decision is made in the game, it always spirals into this next thing happening, and into another thing happening, which inevitably ends up in you losing/winning the game. I've always described it to my friends as "flow-charty" for a lack of better term. I don't feel like "predictable" is the best way to describe it either. Thanks for helping

Comment: Like a "gating event", where the action there determines what happens next?

Comment: Are you describing a linear progression, or the possibility of multiple endings and slightly different events over time?

Comment: Need a little bit more description here.  Games which don't give a lot of choice are often called "linear."  Someone mentioned "snowballing." That's where small early changes build on themselves and make it easier to move in that same direction.  I'm not sure if either of those is what you are wanting here.  We might need a specific example.

Comment: *One thing always leads to another.* Except for the fact that it's a phrase (so I'm not making it an answer), it seems to fit quite well. But you need to clarify your question and provide an example sentence with a space for what you're looking for. (And also mention if such a phrase as this would work.)

Answer (score 2):

I think the usual term would be "snowballing" - imagine a snowball rolling down a snowy hill, picking up more and more snow as it goes, until it is unstoppable. (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/snowballing)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help! "Snowballing" works

Answer (score 2):

You might be describing the ***[domino effect](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/domino-effect)***.

> **Domino effect**
>   *noun, singular*
>
> A situation in which one event causes a whole series of other events to happen one after the other.

Comment: Ok thanks, Domino Effect and Snowballing probably fits best for what I'm trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

Each event is a catalyst for the next event.

> **catalyst** 2: a person or thing that precipitates an event.
>
> "the prime minister's speech acted as a catalyst for debate"

[CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/catalyst)